# how to run php script only on the specified server - based on IP or domain name?

Tags: php, dns, ip, block

Do you know any ways to do that? I want to secure my script to run only in one place. Is it possible?

Comment: You mean, you only want the server itself to be able to run the script? If that's the case, probably the easiest way would be to put it in a directory that's not web-accessible.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Some sorts of licensing?

Comment: I mean rather find the solution used in IonCube technology. I want to avoid probably redistribution of my code. The solutions like $_SERVER is not satisfied. I think about trying doing some obfuscation and enbding in one line code that is checking domain name. But this can be recognize by get_defined_vars() function - Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly the easiest way to do this would be to check a hardware identifier, such as the network card's MAC address, and encrypt the PHP code using something such as Ion Cube so that someone can't simply edit the PHP and change the MAC address being checked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" && $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "mydomain.com") {
   //execute script
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear question.

1. If you mean that you want to restrict your script from being accessible for everyone. And only accessible by special users based of their IP. Then you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to check for the user IP. However you need to be aware that in cases your user is behind proxy you will need to check `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header then to check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Better solution would be to use a firewall on the server by setting `iptable` settings.
2. If you mean that you don't want your script to be accessible at all for anyone, then put the code out-side `DocumentRoot` and run it from CLI.

Please provide more details to have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The option of "noob":

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" && $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "mydomain.com") {
   //execute script
}
```

no is very cool becouse you can do this:

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'; // or IP restricted
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'mydomain.com'; // Or TLD restricted
    // AFTER, you do include():
    require_once('script_of_programmer.php');
?>
```

in this context, any script can do executed in any server...

Unique option is use IonCube or ZEND GUARD